# How to get ID of div javascript is contained within?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to insert javascript inside a div that will retrieve that div's ID, as such:

```
<div id="example"><script>(retrieve id)</script></div>
```

And that would hopefully return "example".  Sorry if this has been asked before, I did check and couldn't find it.  Thanks!

Comment: Can you explain *why* you would need such a thing? Looks a lot like you're shooting yourself in the foot here.

Comment: Just for the purpose of trouble shooting, I have a lot of divs and want to be able to quickly see whether they are all named properly; it'll be quicker than reading through the code and easier to make sure I don't miss anything.

Comment: ignore @Tomalak... he can't see your feet at all ;-) But yeah... you should just hard code it in the script, the same value you hard code as html (i.e. "example")

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13866774/find-the-tag-javascript-is-running-in

Comment: What you propose is rather difficult. Plus there are better methods to do this. If you give a little more context people can show you what you need to do, and do it with less hassle.

Comment: Can't you just get all `div` tags and iterate through the nodeList and console.log `id`s?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following will only work when you load the script synchronously and not with async option.

It simply counts the script tags that do exist when it's loaded, assumes that it's currently the last one (that's why async would probably fail) and then it's querying its parent node, which is your div.

```
<div id="example">
  <script>
    (function () {
        var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script'),
            myScript = scripts[scripts.length - 1]

        console.log(myScript.parentNode.getAttribute('id')); 
     })();

</script>

</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vy5Z7/1/

Answer (score 2):

Are you able to put an id on the script tag?

```
<div id="example">
<script id="myScript">
  var myScript = document.getElementById('myScript');
  var myId = myScript.parentNode.id;
  alert(myId);
</script>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/abzLn/